# JButton's actionPerformed doesn't change JTextField's text by using .setText() method

Tags: java, swing

I have this code... in it it has a problem as in title: JTextField's text doesn't change when clicking the button. I don't know what the problem is, but I think actionPerformed is executed as the message dialog appears. I tried to use a constructor (of class Start) (instead of function "doIt") but it doesn't work either.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PalTransfer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Starter starter = new Starter();
        starter.doIt();
    }
}


class Starter
{
  JFrame PTMainFrame = new JFrame("In/Out - arch - access, ...");
  JTextField TextFieldOfIP = new JTextField(20);
  //String string = "I AM START OF STARTER";


  void doIt()
  {
    PTMainFrame.setSize(900, 400); // Set the frame size
    PTMainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    PTMainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTextField TextFieldOfIP = new JTextField(20);
    JButton jBtn = new JButton("I AM A BUTTON!");

    PTMainFrame.add(jBtn);
    PTMainFrame.add(TextFieldOfIP);

    FlowLayout layoutManager = new FlowLayout(0,10,5);
    PTMainFrame.setLayout(layoutManager);

    TextFieldOfIP.setText("I am doIt() method!"); //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    jBtn.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    PTMainFrame.setVisible(true); // to do // put later
  }

  class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hello?");
      TextFieldOfIP.setText("I am actionPerformed of JButton!");

    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why have you defined this twice.

```
 JTextField TextFieldOfIP = new JTextField(20);
```

Remove it from the **DoIt()** method it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have your class attribute `TextFieldOfIP` that your ButtonListeners is doing the `setText` on. But additional you have a local variable called `TextFieldOfIP` in your `doIt()` method. And thats the object you are placing on your JFrame.

Remove this redefinition line:  `JTextField TextFieldOfIP = new JTextField(20);` of your `doIt()` method. Then you are placing the same object on your JFrame that your ButtonListener is doing the `setText` on and everything will work as expected.